# How to write statistical data into rolling files in java

Tags: java, file, logback

I would like to create rolling files that contains statistical data about my service.
for example, logging each request that contained parameter X with a certain result set.
I have to write these files to comply with other systems statistical data:

- Roll the file every half an hour
- Each file have to have column headers
- I have to follow a strict file name convention such as **tracking.display.1314116577.done**

My service is written in Java.

Since I need to roll files, using loggers seems like a good direction so I have tried an approach where I would log the data using logback logger (my logger of choise), but the conventional rolling file appender cannot role the file every half an hour (or am i wrong?), cannot add column headers and has a strict naming convention of its own.
I have tried to write my own RollingPolicy, but can't find enough resources or examples of how it's done.

Can anyone show/refer me how to accomplish this?
If not, would you recommend a different approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a logback appender.

Take a look at [TimeBasedRollingPolicy](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy) of [RollingFileAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) you can easily roll the file each half hour.

To write the header you can extend RollingFileAppender and add the header based on your needs.

Comment: The rolling policy seems to rely on SimpleDateFormat and I can't make it roll every half an hour, only hour or minute on the minute/hour. how is it easily done? I'll try your lead of extending the file appender. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A very dumb answer: getting logging right costs much time. So it is **easier to implement your own logger** from scratch. It seems you have very rigid requirements. For instance that ".done" - you probably first write it as ".part" and then rename it when done.